# I have forgotten my unlock pin on my iPhone 6. How can I unlock it?

Tags: iphone

Forgot unlock pin on my iPhone 6.  Now it says it is disabled.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot unlock it without the pass code.

You can erase the device via iTunes (standard or via recovery mode) or via iCloud, if Find My iPhone is enabled. After the device has been erased, you can set it up as new and set a new pass code.

Your data is gone though, unless you have a backup.